# HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android, get, httpurlconnection

Есть рабочий код подключения к серверу. Необходимо установить таймаут. `urlconnection.setConnectTimeout    ()` не пашет.

```
 URL url_groups = new URL("http://yarmiit.ru/index.php?name=ASU&op=apk&show_news");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url_groups.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте установить urlconnection.setReadTimeout()

Comment: Эффект тот же. Ждёт более минуты, затем сбрасывает. Хотя устанавливал 20 секунд.

Comment: Вы не хотите перейти хотябы на okHttp? ))) меньше проблем будет и проще во всех отношениях, переписать это не долго будет

Comment: Рассмотрю такой вариант, спасибо.

Comment: Вот ссылка того как это примерно может выглядеть http://pastebin.com/6ms4yC9d в сочетании gson, соответственно okhttp ставите таймаут

Comment: и в gradle в dependencies compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.+"
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'